# L5: Service injection in controller does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am injecting a Service in my controller's constructor but unfortunately it does not seem to be working.

This is the controller file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Glass\Calculator\Services\CalculatorService;

class CalculatorController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * CalculatorController constructor.
     * @param CalculatorService $calculatorService
     */
    public function __construct(CalculatorService $calculatorService)
    {
        $this->calculatorService = $calculatorService;
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function homepage()
    {
        return view('emoji.homepage');
    }
}
```

This is my `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/','CalculatorController@homepage');
```

And that is the stack trace:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 809: Class Glass\Calculator\Services\CalculatorService does not exist

    in Container.php line 809
    at ReflectionParameter->getClass() in Container.php line 809
    at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 790
    at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\CalculatorController', array()) in Container.php line 644
    at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\CalculatorController', array()) in Application.php line 709
    at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\CalculatorController') in Route.php line 203
    at Route->getController() in Route.php line 316
    at Route->controllerMiddleware() in Route.php line 278
    at Route->gatherMiddleware() in Router.php line 666
    at Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(object(Route)) in Router.php line 646
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I have tried several times `composer dump-autoload` but with no luck. Any ideas are more than welcome. 
In case you need `composer.json` could be responsible I can paste it in here.

**UPDATE**

So, this is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

CalculatorService: `namespace Glass\Calculator\Services;`

and as a file placed under `app\Glass\Calculator\Services;`

Comment: Almost sure that you have  not registered the custom namespace.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? I am sure it will be easy but is this happening in composer.json?

Comment: Sure. If you have a class file under an unregistered namespace, that is, other than not installed via composer or not under `app/` (App namespace) dir, you MUST register namespace in autoload file.

Comment: Right, I see. Thanks for that, @felipsmartins.  I have updated my question, so it might easier for people to understand the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors like `Class Whatever\Class does not exist`, when you are using PSR-4, doesn't care about `composer update`. Composer autoloads them automatically, and usually the problem is one of these:

1) The class file is misplaced. Check if it is in the proper directory. As example, having this as base namespace for your app:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Glass\\": "app/Glass/"
}
```

Means that your files should be

```
/var/www/myapp/app/User.php
/var/www/myapp/app/Glass/Calculator/Services/CalculatorService.php
```

2) The class file is not correctly namespaced. Sometimes we copy files and forget to change the namespace, or we have a typo on them.

3) The class file has a bug. Sometimes if you have a serious problem in the file, like a missing `}`, PHP is not able to compile that file and then it basically acts like the file never existed.

Comment: If You put it app\ the namespace should be `namespace App\Glass\Calculator\Services`

Comment: Ok sorted! The actual problem was that I need  to prefix the namespace with `App\ ` as @Pyton suggests.
Question now is how  to make `Glass\Calculator\Services` working (without `App\`)

Comment: Yeah, so it was number 2) your file was not correctly namespaced.

Comment: @thitami You have to create new namespace root in composer.json which will be outside app\ dir.